# BindingError during binding to viewmodel's interface implementation via F#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, f#

Hello guys and sorry for such a long question, but...

I have a C# interface like this one:

```cs
public interface ISimpleViewModel
{
    string SimpleText { get; }
}
```

Then I have a F# type inherited from it:

```ml
type SimpleViewModel() = 
    interface ISimpleViewModel with
        member this.SimpleText
            with get() = "Hello again!"
```

Also I have a C# inheritor:

```cs
public class SimpleCSViewModel : ISimpleViewModel
{
    public string SimpleText
    {
        get { return "Just testing"; }
    }
}
```

Eventually I have a super simple WPF application which MainWindow ctor is injected with ISimpleViewModel instance this way:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(ISimpleViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ISimpleViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as ISimpleViewModel; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

And of course I have a TextBlock on my Window which Text Property is binded to SimpleText.

Everyting works in case when I'm injecting C# instance. But I receive BindingError that property could be found in case of F# instance. Why it could be so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know enough about how WPF binding works to be sure, but one thing to keep in mind is that interfaces in F# are *explicitly* implemented (meaning that the implementing methods are actually non-public), but by default they're implicit in C#.  What happens if you use an explicit interface implementation in C# instead?  If this is indeed the problem then the simplest fix would just be to create a public property on your F# type which duplicates the behavior of the interface implementation.

Comment: For my case it works fine if I will inject ViewModels.SimpleViewModel (where ViewModels is a module name in F#) and sue it all over the MainWindow partial class. Also your solution to create a public property with the SameName which has also same behavour works just fine :) So thanks you :)